# Scala REPL unable to import packge

Tags: scala, import, read-eval-print-loop

I'm trying to import `com.lambdaworks.crypto.SCryptUtil` ([from crypto](https://github.com/wg/scrypt/tree/master/src/main/java/com/lambdaworks/crypto)) in the Scala REPL. I'm running the REPL from the Java directory containing com/lambdaworks/crypto.

The REPL can't find `com.lambdaworks.crypto.SCryptUtil`, but it can autocomplete up to `com.lambdaworks.crypto` but can't find anything after that.

When I used the REPL in the IntelliJ IDEA after including the package in my project, I was able to find the `SCryptUtil` class.

Am I missing some classpath parameters that are required for import?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The REPL won't compile the Java code for you—it's only autocompleting that far because it's aware of the directory structure, but once it gets to the `crypto` directory it won't find any class files.

You can see this more dramatically by moving up a directory and opening a new REPL—you'll be able to autocomplete `import java.com.lambdaworks.crypto`, even though that's obviously not a real package hierarchy.

In this case you can move to the project root, run `mvn compile` to compile the Java code, and then start the REPL like this (still in the project root):

```
scala -classpath target/classes
```

Now you can import `com.lambdaworks.crypto.SCryptUtil`.

This only works because the project doesn't have any runtime dependencies, though—in other cases you may need either to add other things to the classpath, to build a JAR with the dependencies baked in (e.g. with the [Maven Assembly plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/)), or to use the `mvn scala:console` goal of the Maven [Scala plugin](http://davidb.github.com/scala-maven-plugin/index.html).

Comment: In my case, I already did `sbt package` into a `target/...jar` and a `:require` in the (spark) scala repl, but it still won't import the path it tab completes. But I am using 2.13, so and noticed it doesn't seem to have other basic features like `:history` so maybe it's just a bug or not supported yet ... :(