# How to import package into Scala REPL?

Tags: scala, sbt, read-eval-print-loop

How do I import a package into Scala's REPL? 
I am trying to import this package called funsets which has an object named "FunSets".
I tried several variations of `import funsets._` and `import funsets._;` etc but it is still not importing the functions and object in the package.

Comment: What is funsets? Is it in a jar? Is it a compiled class file? Is it a scala file? Is it a managed dependency in an external repository like maven central?

Comment: funsets is the name of the package that has an object called FunSets in it. It is just in a scala object file.

Comment: You need to run `console` from *within the sbt shell*. Then, sbt will compile whatever is defined in funsets and automatically add it in your Scala shell. From there, you'll be able to do `import funsets._`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**One way is to compile the "scala classes" and put those in [`classpath`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2396759/432903).**

Example,

**1) Say you have a class `funsets.FunSets.scala`**

```
package funsets                                                                                        

object FunSets {                                                                                       

  def fun = "very fun"                                                                                 

}
```

**2) Compile the class first using `scalac`.** (If you use `sbt` then `sbt compile` would put compiled classes in `target/` folder)

```
scalac FunSets.scala
```

You will see the `funsets` folder/package created,

```
$ ls -l
total 16
-rw-r--r--  1 updupd  NA\Domain Users   63 Dec 18 11:05 FunSets.scala
drwxr-xr-x  4 updupd  NA\Domain Users  136 Dec 18 11:06 funsets
```

**3) Then start REPL with `funsets` package in classpath**

```
$ scala -classpath .
Welcome to Scala 2.12.3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_151).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> import funsets._
import funsets._
```

*Note: if you use `sbt compile`, put `target/classes` in classpath.*

Access Funsets singleton,

```
scala> FunSets.fun
res0: String = very fun
```

Also read [Scala REPL unable to import packge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13402469/scala-repl-unable-to-import-packge)

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the appropriate jar(s) to the classpath as well using the `-cp <jar files>` argument when starting the repl.  Alternatively you can use the `:require <jar file>` directive from the repl to load a jar after you've already started the session.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have some code in a scala file, you can load external scala files from the scala repl using the `:load` command. More info [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383436/load-scala-file-into-interpreter-to-use-functions).

Comment: In the REPL, I tried doing `:load "C:...full file path name` and whole bunch of variations. I even tried doing `:paste "full file path name" 
But it keeps saying like "usage: :load -v file" or "usage: :paste -raw file"

Comment: If you start the repl in the same directory as your file you should be able to just do `:load myFile.scala`.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35070783/load-a-scala-file-from-command-line), you might have to use the `:lo` command instead of `:load`, in windows even though it should have the same behavior.