# How to import an user defined package into scala REPL automatically when scala REPL is started?

Tags: scala, import

When scala REPL starts some default packages like 
scala.lang._ , 
scala.Predef are automatically available.Suppose I have my own package like com.raghhuraamm.rUtils._

> How to import this package automatically when REPL starts? Is there a
>   way or I just have to type "import com.raghhuraamm.rUtils._ " every
>   time I start scala REPL?

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47874731/how-to-import-package-into-scala-repl

Comment: @ChaitanyaWaikar Neither is this question about SBT, nor do the linked answers say anything about `import`ing packages automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could use `sbt console` to launch the REPL, you can create a `build.sbt` containing this line:

`initialCommands in Compile in console += "import com.raghhuraamm.rUtils._"`

Source: https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Inspecting-Settings.html

Answer (score 0):

Create a script (`myPreload.scala`, say) that contains all the imports that you want:

```
// in myPreload.scala
import com.raghhuraamm.rUtils._
```

Assuming that the classes are packaged in `my.jar`, start the `scala` repl as follows:

```
scala -cp path/to/my.jar -i some/other/path/to/myPreload.scala
```