# SBT-compiled package not working properly in Scala REPL

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm developing a Scala package using an sbt project scheme through IntelliJ.  I wanted to use the classes in this package in the Scala REPL, so I followed the instructions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47874731/how-to-import-package-into-scala-repl).  Namely,

1. Navigate to where my package's source files are located (MyProject/src/main/scala/mypackage)
2. Run "sbt compile"
3. Navigate to where sbt stores the compiled source files (MyProject/src/main/scala/mypackage/target/scala-2.12/classes/mytest)
4. Run "scala -cp ."

This all works fine until I try to create an instance of one of my package's classes and I get the error `MyClass does not have a constructor`.  However, if I just paste the class definitions into the Scala REPL, I can create instances with no errors.  What am I doing wrong here?

---

As a reproducible example, I created a package `mytest` with two files `TraitOne.scala` and `ClassOne.scala`.  The first file looks like

```
package mytest

trait TraitOne {
  val a: Double
  def aMinus(x: Double): Double = a - x
}
```

The second file looks like

```
package mytest

class ClassOne(val a: Double) extends TraitOne {
  def aPlus(x: Double): Double = a + x 
}
```

If I follow steps 1 - 4 as listed above and write `val temp = new ClassOne(1.0)`, I get the error `ClassOne does not have a constructor`.  But if I paste

```
trait TraitOne {
  val a: Double
  def aMinus(x: Double): Double = a - x
}
class ClassOne(val a: Double) extends TraitOne {
  def aPlus(x: Double): Double = a + x 
}
```

into the REPL, `val temp = new ClassOne(1.0)` works fine.

Comment: Why not just run `sbt console`? Or, if you want to use those classes on other environments, try `sbt package` to generate a single **JAR** with all your classes, and then pass that **JAR** to the `cp` argument.

Comment: I tried the JAR method, navigating to `MyProject/src/main/scala/mypackage` and running `sbt package`.  This was successful, and a `.jar` file appeared at `MyProject/src/main/scala/mypackage/target/scala-2.12/classes/mypackage_2.12-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`. However, when I run `scala -cp pathtojar`, neither `import mypackage` nor `val temp = new ClassOne(1.0)` work.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Why exactly do you need this? If you just want to have a **REPL** with your classes you can always use `sbt console`. If you want to distribute your classes to other users, there are other alternatives.

Comment: To answer your question - I'm writing a package while reading a Scala textbook to put the concepts to practice.  It might be bad practice (please tell me if it is), but I was planning on playing with the package's classes as I create them in order to gauge user friendliness / feature completeness.  

I tried your suggestion of `sbt console` from within `MyProject` and it worked! Thanks so much for your advice.

Comment: Zack, that is pretty cool. Yesterday I was already falling of sleep and I read your last message wrong. You said that `sbt console` worked and somehow I understood that it didn't work. I am glad it helped. I deleted my last comment _(since it doesn't make sense anymore)_ I would suggest you do the same with your last comment since it is off-topic to the site right now.

Answer (score 0):

Run `scala -cp MyProject/src/main/scala/mypackage/target/scala-2.12/classes`

Don't include the package in classpath